# "Requirement of" - correct preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Is the use of the word "of" correct in the following sentence, or this there a better word?
The meaning should be "which requirement the platform must fulfil".

> The most important requirements *of* the platform are performance and functionality.

Comment: *Of* is a preposition. I have edited accordingly. Also changed *right* to *correct*, as it makes for an easier read. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say 'for', but it's understandable as is.